# Installing Source Library -- uriparser

Tags: package-management, software-installation, make, automake

I am new to the ubuntu and linux community and have decided to migrate my current C project to my new ubuntu workstation. I am currently working on a simple HTTP proxy as an educational personal project. I am fairly new to socket programming, C, and the need for specific libraries such as uriparser as well.

I am also open to different alternatives to parsing a URL in C if anyone has any suggestions.

**RELEVANT INFO:**

I downloaded a tar.bz2 archive from [here](http://uriparser.sourceforge.net/), unpacked the "tarball", and ran the configure script I found in the unpacked directory.

Unfortunately, a following attpemt to "**make**" and "**make install**" were not successful as no makefile was located. I'm guessing this is because the configure script did not run properly. However when checking the output of the script once again, I could not find any relevant instructions.

I wasn't able to locate any sort of INSTALL or README file in the unpacked directory to aid with the install. Maybe I should be looking for a different type of instructional? The unpacked directory *also* contains the following:

(these are not all of them, but some I think may be relevent)

```
Makefile.am
Makefile.in 
configure.ac
aclocal.m4
build-aux                         < -- DIR
    install.sh
    config.sub
    missing
```

Anyway, If anyone has had experience with this sort of source install, any help is appreciated!

**Edit:**

./configure output

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
/usr/local/src/uriparser-0.8.4/build-aux/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/usr/local/src/uriparser-0.8.4/build-aux/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for wprintf... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for CPPTEST... no
configure: error: Please install libcpptest 1.1.0 or later.
            Alternatively, you could pass --disable-test to the call to configure.
            However, it is not recommended to disable the test suite.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the configuration file again by

1. Open terminal and goto the extracted file
2. run command `autoreconf`
3. run command `automake --add-missing` if you get any error
4. Then run `./configure`
5. Then run `make`
6. Then rin `sudo make install`

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, this didn't end up working. Error after running "make" was "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."

Comment: did you install the required packages. can you paste the output of previous command

Comment: If you are talking about autoreconf and automake then I believe so. There were no errors after running autoreconf and the after running make, the output was "make *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop. "

Comment: i am taking about `./configure' post the output of it.

Comment: Sorry, was out for the weekend. I updated the post with the output. Is it necessary to install libcpptest? When run with the specified flags, it calls for installing Doxygen. Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to install libcpptest `apt-get install libcpptest-dev` the make file was not made.

Comment: I was running into this same issue about libcpptest not being found even though I had installed libcpptest-dev and libcpptest0.  Turns out pkg-config was not installed on my system